# How to install pip to python 2.7.10 on mac

Tags: python

I'm really new to python and scripts. I want to install pip package to my python 2.7.10. So can everyone clearly explain the following instructions to me?

"First, securely download get-pip.py"

What does it mean by "securely" and where should I save the file "get-pip.py"?

"Run the following:  python get-pip.py"

Should I run this scripts in the MAC terminal or in python?

Thanks a lot for your time!

Answer (score 4):

Basically, this consists in:

downloading get-pip.py (https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py). Be sure to do this by following a trusted link since you will have to run the script as root.
    call sudo python get-pip.py

Comment: To round out the answer, yes, you need to run this in terminal.